# Identify jumps from 0 to 1 using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table with the variable of interest `x`. I would like to create another variable that indicates a jump in `x` from exactly 0 to 1, meaning the variable has been 0 until a certain year and 1 in all years following after that. This should by done by `id_d`.

Is there an easy data.table way for doing this?

Original data.table:

```
 fullDat <- data.table(id_d = rep(letters[1:3], each=12), 
                  year=rep(1:12, 3), 
                  x = c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 7), 0,1,0,1,2,2,4, rep(5,5), 1, rep(0, 3), rep(1, 8)))

    id_d year x
  1:    a    1 0
  2:    a    2 0
  3:    a    3 0
  4:    a    4 0
  5:    a    5 0
  6:    a    6 1
  7:    a    7 1
  8:    a    8 1
  9:    a    9 1
 10:    a   10 1
 11:    a   11 1
 12:    a   12 1
 13:    b    1 0
 14:    b    2 1
 15:    b    3 0
 16:    b    4 1
 17:    b    5 2
 18:    b    6 2
 19:    b    7 4
 20:    b    8 5
 21:    b    9 5
 22:    b   10 5
 23:    b   11 5
 24:    b   12 5
 25:    c    1 1
 26:    c    2 0
 27:    c    3 0
 28:    c    4 0
 29:    c    5 1
 30:    c    6 1
 31:    c    7 1
 32:    c    8 1
 33:    c    9 1
 34:    c   10 1
 35:    c   11 1
 36:    c   12 1
id_d year x
```

What the result should look like:

```
    id_d year x jump
  1:    a    1 0    0
  2:    a    2 0    0
  3:    a    3 0    0
  4:    a    4 0    0
  5:    a    5 0    0
  6:    a    6 1    1
  7:    a    7 1    0
  8:    a    8 1    0
  9:    a    9 1    0
 10:    a   10 1    0
 11:    a   11 1    0
 12:    a   12 1    0
 13:    b    1 0    0
 14:    b    2 1    0
 15:    b    3 0    0
 16:    b    4 1    0
 17:    b    5 2    0
 18:    b    6 2    0
 19:    b    7 4    0
 20:    b    8 5    0
 21:    b    9 5    0
 22:    b   10 5    0
 23:    b   11 5    0
 24:    b   12 5    0
 25:    c    1 1    0
 26:    c    2 0    0
 27:    c    3 0    0
 28:    c    4 0    0
 29:    c    5 1    0
 30:    c    6 1    0
 31:    c    7 1    0
 32:    c    8 1    0
 33:    c    9 1    0
 34:    c   10 1    0
 35:    c   11 1    0
 36:    c   12 1    0
id_d year x jump
```

Answer (score 3):

> the variable has been 0 until a certain year and 1 in all years following

```
# find rows to assign one
wDT = fullDat[, .(year = year[with(rle(x), 
  if (identical(values, c(0, 1))) first(lengths) + 1L
  else 0L
)]), by=id_d]

# initialize to zero
fullDat[, jump := 0L ]
# update join to assign ones
fullDat[wDT, on=.(id_d, year), jump := 1L ]
```

It is not necessary to make the intermediate table `wDT`; writing the full code for it into the final statement would work too. In fact, it could all be in one line if wanted, something like...

```
DT[, x := 0L][code_for_wDT, on=on_cols, x := 1L]
```

---

Alternately, instead of a join, just use the row numbers from `.I`:

```
# find rows to assign one
w = fullDat[, with(rle(x), .I[
  if (identical(values, c(0, 1))) first(lengths) + 1L
  else 0L
]), by=id_d]$V1

# initialize to zero
fullDat[, jump := 0L ]
# update to assign ones
fullDat[w, jump := 1L ]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do

```
fullDat[, jump := {i1 <- which.max(x)
       if(all(x[i1:.N]==1)) replace(rep(0, .N), i1, 1) else 0}, 
           id_d]
fullDat
#    id_d year x jump
# 1:    a    1 0    0
# 2:    a    2 0    0
# 3:    a    3 0    0
# 4:    a    4 0    0
# 5:    a    5 0    0
# 6:    a    6 1    1
# 7:    a    7 1    0
# 8:    a    8 1    0
# 9:    a    9 1    0
#10:    a   10 1    0
#11:    a   11 1    0
#12:    a   12 1    0
#13:    b    1 0    0
#14:    b    2 1    0
#15:    b    3 0    0
#16:    b    4 1    0
#17:    b    5 2    0
#18:    b    6 2    0
#19:    b    7 4    0
#20:    b    8 5    0
#21:    b    9 5    0
#22:    b   10 5    0
#23:    b   11 5    0
#24:    b   12 5    0
#25:    c    1 1    0
#26:    c    2 0    0
#27:    c    3 0    0
#28:    c    4 0    0
#29:    c    5 1    0
#30:    c    6 1    0
#31:    c    7 1    0
#32:    c    8 1    0
#33:    c    9 1    0
#34:    c   10 1    0
#35:    c   11 1    0
#36:    c   12 1    0
```

---

Or a slightly more compact option is

```
fullDat[, jump := if(all(cumsum(diff(x)) %in% c(0,1))) c(0, diff(x)) else 0 ,id_d]
```

Comment: Fyi, this breaks on `DT = data.table(id_d = rep("d",4), year=1:4, x = c(0,1,0,1))` (actually gives different results for the long vs "compact" versions)

Comment: @Frank I didn't test all the cases

Answer (score 0):

```
fullDat[, jump := (cumsum(x==0)==(1:.N - 1L)) & (rev(cumsum(rev(x==1))) == .N:1), id_d]
```

How this works:

1. `cumsum(x==0) == (1:.N - 1L)` checks that the number of zeros up to and including this row is equal to the number of previous rows
2. `rev(cumsum(rev(x==1))) == .N:1` checks that the number of ones, counting from the final row backwards (down to and including this row), is equal to the number of rows from here to the end

Comment: Too clever by half, in my opinion. It breaks on `DT = data.table(id_d = rep("d",4), year=1:4, x = c(0,1,0,2))` for example.

Comment: Good point @Frank, I've added addtional logical tests to check for zero and 1 values. Should catch these cases now

Comment: Yep, now I think it works for all cases. I still find it unnecessarily obscure, though.